# В датафрейме добавить столбец с положительными значениями

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В датафрейме my_statесть столбец 'n_users' с положительными и отрицательными значениями. Надо добавить еще один столбец 't', но только с положительными значениями из столбец 'n_users'. Делаю так: `my_stat['t'] = my_stat.n_users>0`, но получаю столбец t с булевыми значениями, а как его сделать с числовыми значениями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_stat['t'] = my_stat.loc[my_stat['n_users'] > 0, 'n_users']
```

Пример:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, size=[10, 4]), columns=list("abcd"))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    a  b  c  d
0  -6  5 -9 -2
1   0 -1 -6 -6
2   0  4 -4  2
3   3  4  4 -2
4   2  8  1  7
5  -8 -6 -8  9
6  -3  3  3  9
7  -3 -4  8 -4
8 -10  7  0  2
9   3 -2  5 -5

In [3]: df["new"] = df.loc[df["d"] > 0, "d"]

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
    a  b  c  d  new
0  -6  5 -9 -2  NaN
1   0 -1 -6 -6  NaN
2   0  4 -4  2  2.0
3   3  4  4 -2  NaN
4   2  8  1  7  7.0
5  -8 -6 -8  9  9.0
6  -3  3  3  9  9.0
7  -3 -4  8 -4  NaN
8 -10  7  0  2  2.0
9   3 -2  5 -5  NaN

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]:
a        int32
b        int32
c        int32
d        int32
new    float64
dtype: object
```